# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadBlockList returns 0 blocks

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting a list of IListBlobItems using `CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs`.  I'm then looping over each entry to show the size of the blob using the following code:

```
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobs)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
            { }
            else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                IEnumerable<ListBlockItem> blocks = blockBlob.DownloadBlockList(new BlobRequestOptions { BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.All });
                Console.WriteLine(blockBlob.Name.PadRight(50, ' ') + 
                   blocks.Sum(b => b.Size));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Uri.LocalPath);
            }

        }
```

However, when I check the count on the variable `blocks`, it is always 0.  Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe (not 100% sure) that `DownloadBlockList()` is only valid if the blob was initially uploaded in blocks, rather than all at once. That may be why you get no blocks back.

In any case, you seem to only want the total size of the blob anyway. So using the `blob.Properties.Length` property may be an easier approach:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
Console.WriteLine(blockBlob.Name.PadRight(50, ' ') + blockBlob.Properties.Length);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should be checking for a CloudBlob instead of a CloudBlockBlob type.  If you add another else if with that, do you get the sizes?  If that isn't it, do you see the code going into the else if and the b.size is just zero?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think only CouldBlockBlobs have blocks, though.  In fact, the CloudBlob doesn't have a DownloadBlockList method on it.  Only the CloudBlockBlob has that method.